# CSS: Replacing a Fade Out Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code fades out an image on load after a delay. Is it possible to fade in a new image after the blue circle fades out? http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/8puvn/

html

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Javascript

```
(function($) {

$.fn.fadeDelay = function(delay) {

    var that = $(this);
    delay = delay || 3000;

    return that.each(function() {

        $(that).queue(function() {

            setTimeout(function() {

                $(that).dequeue();

            }, delay);
        });

        $(that).fadeOut('slow');
    });
};

})(jQuery);

$('#test').fadeDelay(4000);
```

CSS

```
#test {
margin: 2em auto;
width: 10em;
height: 10em;
background: #069;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: What's your idea behind this? Where's your *Second "image"* ?

Comment: I don't get what's the purpose of `fadeDelay` when you've could easily do that with: `$('#test').delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");`

Comment: Idea? I'd like to fade in a new element after the blue circle fades out.

Comment: Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/8PuVN/41/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it's possible, in jQuery animations second parameter is the function that runs after animation completes. [More info](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```js
(function($) {

    $.fn.fadeDelay = function(delay) {

        var that = $(this);
        delay = delay || 3000;

        return that.each(function() {

            $(that).queue(function() {

                setTimeout(function() {

                    $(that).dequeue();

                }, delay);
            });

            $(that).fadeOut('slow',function(){
              $('#test2').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$('#test').fadeDelay(4000);
```

```css
#test {
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    background: #069;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#test2 {
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    background: #f69;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PuVN/40/)

Answer (score 2):

do your fade in code inside `fadeOut` call back.

```
$(that).fadeOut('slow', function(){

//do fade in

});
```

---

sample

```js
(function($) {


  $.fn.fadeDelay = function(delay, awake) {
    $(awake).hide();
    var that = $(this);
    delay = delay || 3000;

    return that.each(function() {

      $(that).queue(function() {

        setTimeout(function() {

          $(that).dequeue();

        }, delay);
      });

      $(that).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(awake).fadeIn('slow');
      });
    });
  };

})(jQuery);

$('#test').fadeDelay(4000, "#test2"); //pass jquery selector, which element to show
```

```css
.circle {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#test {
  background: #069;
}
#test2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="circle"></div>
<div id="test2" class="circle"></div>
```